# Updating data in multiple tables from datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, npgsql, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to display data from multiple tables to a data grid and let the user edit the data and have it saved in my sql server.

I get an error message: Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

I declared my variables like so:

```
private NpgsqlDataAdapter da;
private DataSet ds;
private NpgsqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
```

At load I've got this code:

```
string SELECT = "SELECT Table_1.Col_1, Table_1.Col_2, Table_2.Col_1, Table_2.Col_2 FROM Table_1 INNER JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID";

conn.Open();
da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(SELECT, conn);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

And my save buton looks like this:

```
cmdBuilder = new NpgsqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Update(ds);
```

I believe it's because SqlCommandBuilder is not suppose to work with multiple tables. Is there any other way of doing this?

I only need the data updated on Table_1 (user won't edit any data from Table_2) but I need data from both tables displayed on the datagrid.

Comment: Make sure the primary key of both tables are in the select clause, if that is the case then the SqlCommandBuilder might just be able to do it for you

Comment: Added both of them. Still the same outcome.

Comment: You can set the SelectCommand of the adapter to a query that only selects the first table fields and than call da.UpdateCommand = NpgsqlCommandBuilder .GetUpdateCommand(true)Clone();